# Click HTML Table Row and Open Form With Pre-Filled Data

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am new to coding in general.  I have taught myself basic HTML, CSS, and Javascript to try and build an simple web app to help my marina run more efficient.  I have been working on this one aspect for at least 6 hours, and cannot find a way to make it happen.

What I am trying to do is allow my techs to search the HTML Table, which is populated by a Google Sheet dynamically, and when they click the row for the customer they want to work on I need it to open the form entry page with the Customer Name, Boat Name, and Work Order number pre-filled.  Thank you for any help you can offer.

Form page that each tech uses to enter their name, customer name, boat name, work order number, description of labor and hours spent, and part numbers and part quantities.  This is the form I am hoping to pre-load with data from the HTML Table after the tech clicks on the entry they wish to add time and parts to.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
   <?!= include("page-css") ?>
 
 </head>

<body>
  
    <a href = "https://script.google.com/a/obmc.com/macros/s/AKfycbxGT-s3hnCXs4gI-E0Qo5-C87M5yeDd3FhLto6txnQ/exec" id = "labor" class="waves-effect waves-light btn indigo darken-4"><i class="material-icons left">chevron_left</i>Home</a>
   
   
   <div class = "container">
    <h1>Labor Entry </h1>
    </div>

      
      <div class = "container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12 m8 l8">
         <div class="text">Tech</div>
          <input type="text" id="tech" class="autocomplete">
         </div>
      </div>
     </div>

     
     <div class = "container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12 m8 l8">
           <div class="text">Customer Name</div>
          <input type="text" id="customer" class="autocomplete">
        </div>
       </div> 
      </div>
      
      
      
      <div class = "container">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12 m8 l8">
         <div class="text">Boat Name</div>
          <input id="boat" type="text" class="validate">
        </div>
       </div>
       </div>

      <div class = "container">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
        <div class="text">Work Order</div>
         <input type="text" id="work order">
          
        </div>
       </div> 
      </div> 
     
     
     <div class = "container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6 m6 l6">
           <div class="text">Description of Work</div>
          <textarea id="desc" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
        </div>  

        
        <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s2 m2 l2">
                <div class="text">Hours</div>
          <input id="time" type="text" class="validate">
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class = "container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12 m8 l8">
           <div class="text">Part Number</div>
          <input type="text" id="part" class="autocomplete">
        </div>
 
 
 
        
        <div class="input-field col s2 m2 l2">
                <div class="text">Quantity</div>
          <input id="qty" type="text" class="validate">
        </div>
      </div>
</div>

     
          <div class = "container">
        <div class="row">
     <button id = "submit" class="btn- waves-effect waves-light btn-large indigo darken-4"><i class="material-icons left">directions_boat</i>Submit</button>
       
     <button id = "clear" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large indigo darken-4"><i class="material-icons left">clear_all</i>Clear Form</button>
        </div> <!-- CLOSE ROW -->
          </div>  <!-- CLOSE CONTAINER -->
          
          
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
   <?!= include("page-js") ?>
             
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the Searchable HTML Table that is populated dynamically by a Google Sheet where we enter in new work order information.  This would be what the tech is presented with first, and after narrowing their search or scrolling to their selection they would click it and have the Form page load with the customer, boat, and work order pre-filled.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>JavaScript Table Filter Search</title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
        h3 span {
            font-size: 22px;
        }
        h3 input.search-input {
            width: 300px;
            margin-left: auto;
            float: right
        }
        .mt32 {
            margin-top: 32px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="mt32">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 align = "center">
            <span>Work Order Search</span>
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control search-input" data-table="customers-list"/>
        </h1>
        <table class="table table-striped mt32 customers-list" id = "display-table" onclick="theFunction()" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th align ="center">Customer Name</th>
                    <th align ="center">Boat Name</th>
                    <th align ="center">Work Order</th>
                    <th align ="center">Description of Work</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id = "table-body">
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script>
        (function(document) {
            'use strict';

            var TableFilter = (function(myArray) {
                var search_input;

                function _onInputSearch(e) {
                    search_input = e.target;
                    var tables = document.getElementsByClassName(search_input.getAttribute('data-table'));
                    myArray.forEach.call(tables, function(table) {
                        myArray.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {
                            myArray.forEach.call(tbody.rows, function(row) {
                                var text_content = row.textContent.toLowerCase();
                                var search_val = search_input.value.toLowerCase();
                                row.style.display = text_content.indexOf(search_val) > -1 ? '' : 'none';
                            });
                        });
                    });
                }

                return {
                    init: function() {
                        var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('search-input');
                        myArray.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
                            input.oninput = _onInputSearch;
                        });
                    }
                };
            })(Array.prototype);

            document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
                if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
                    TableFilter.init();
                }
            });

        })(document)
        
        var data = []
        
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
        
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable).getTableData()
        
             
              
        })
        
        
 function generateTable(dataArray){
 
 dataArray.forEach(function(r){
    var tbody = document.getElementById("table-body")
        var row = document.createElement("tr")
        var col1 = document.createElement("td")
        col1.textContent = r[0]
        var col2 = document.createElement("td")
        col2.textContent = r[1]
        var col3 = document.createElement("td")
        col3.textContent = r[2]
        var col4 = document.createElement("td")
        col4.textContent = r[3]
        row.appendChild(col1)
        row.appendChild(col2)
        row.appendChild(col3)
        row.appendChild(col4)
        tbody.appendChild(row)
        
        })
 
 
 
 }


                
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm still not very good at adding questions either.

Comment: Your post is clear now, but what's the problem you're facing? Is there a specific thing that's not working or is nothing working?

Comment: Your question is rather broad.  I don't want to have to debug your entire script.  Pick a specific problem you're having trouble with and ask a question that focuses on that one issue.  The easiest way to build complex solutions is by tackling them one section at a time.

Comment: When a user clicks on the HTML table row I was hoping to take the Customer Name, Boat Name, and Work Order values and plug them into the form on the first page.  That way the user doesn't have type those values in, they will be there and they can begin entering labor and parts information.  I hope that makes things more clear.

Comment: Please let me know if there is something else I can explain to make it easier to assist.  I have an HTML Table that consists of 'Customer Name', 'Boat Name', 'Work Order', and 'Description of Work'.  The table filters as the tech types, and I want them to be able to click on the HTML table row and have it open the Form Page with the 'Customer Name', 'Boat Name', and 'Work Order' filled in already so that the tech can just add their time or parts and submit the form.  Thank you for any help.

Comment: I think you need to simplify your question as others have suggested. Especially since running the second snippet of HTML has no records, its just an empty table, probably because it calls data that we don't have access to. Try a simple problem first, like using a button to put text into a text box, then build it up until you can apply it to your use case. Or build a simplified example in your question with data that we can access and experiment with without having to guess. You seem to be trying to tackle too much, too quickly!